# Python Multithreading: Synchronize file writing in multiple processes and threads

Tags: python, multithreading, file, synchronization

The idea of the program is to check for domains/subdomains living (via http/https protocol) in the subdomains.txt file.

I did this by using HEAD requests to domains/subdomains and receiving the response status code. If the status code is available, the domain or subdomain is live. (`load_url_http` function)

In the below code, I have used 12 processes. With each process, I launch 50 threads to handle sending HEAD requests and writing files.

My problem was that the domains/subdomain checked when written to the file were missing.

**python-request-multil.py**

```py
import multiprocessing
import random
import threading
import time
import requests


MAX_NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
MAX_NUMBER_OF_THREADS_IN_EACH_PROCESS = 30
PROTOCOL = "http"
TIMEOUT = 4
START_TIME = time.time()


def load_url_http(protocol: str, domains: list[str], timeout: int = 10):
    with open("live_subdomains.txt", "a") as live_domains_file:
        for domain in domains:
            try:
                conn = requests.head(protocol + "://" + domain, timeout=timeout)
                if conn.status_code is not None:
                    live_domains_file.write(f"{protocol}://{domain}\n")
            except Exception:
                pass
    return


def create_threads_for_process(protocol: str, domains: list[str], timeout: int = 10):
    # create threads
    threads_list = []
    threads_urls = {}
    start = 0
    number_of_threads_to_open = len(domains) if len(domains) < MAX_NUMBER_OF_THREADS_IN_EACH_PROCESS \
        else MAX_NUMBER_OF_THREADS_IN_EACH_PROCESS
    for i in range(1, number_of_threads_to_open + 1):
        # distribute the work of this process evenly between all the threads
        if i != number_of_threads_to_open:
            threads_urls[i] = domains[start:(len(domains) // number_of_threads_to_open) * i]
            start = (len(domains) // number_of_threads_to_open) * i
        else:
            threads_urls[i] = domains[start:]
        # create and start the thread
        thread = threading.Thread(target=load_url_http,
                                  args=(protocol, threads_urls[i], timeout,),
                                  daemon=True)
        thread.start()
        threads_list.append(thread)
    # wait for all threads to finish
    while threads_list:
        for thread in threads_list:
            if not thread.is_alive():
                threads_list.remove(thread)
        time.sleep(0.8)


def main():
    with open("live_subdomains.txt", "w") as file:
        file.write("")
    with open("subdomains.txt", "r") as file:
        urls = file.read().split("\n")
    random.shuffle(urls)  # shuffle the urls list
    # create the processes
    processes_list = []
    processes_urls = {}
    start = 0
    number_of_processes_to_open = len(urls) if len(urls) < MAX_NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES else MAX_NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES
    for i in range(1, number_of_processes_to_open + 1):
        if i != number_of_processes_to_open:
            # give each process an even amount of work
            processes_urls[i] = urls[start:(len(urls) // number_of_processes_to_open) * i]
            start = (len(urls) // number_of_processes_to_open) * i
        else:
            # the last process will get a bit more / a bit less in
            # case len(urls) isn't dividable by number_of_processes_to_open
            processes_urls[i] = urls[start:]
        # create the process, start it and add to processes list
        process = multiprocessing.Process(target=create_threads_for_process,
                                          args=(PROTOCOL, processes_urls[i], TIMEOUT,),
                                          daemon=True)
        process.start()
        processes_list.append(process)
    # wait for all processes to finish
    while multiprocessing.active_children():
        time.sleep(0.8)
    # print result
    with open("live_subdomains.txt", "r") as live_urls_file:
        live_count = len(live_urls_file.read().split("\n")) - 1  # -1 empty line at the end
    print(f"\n[+] Live domain: {live_count}/{len(urls)}", end="")
    print("\n--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - START_TIME))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Run:**

```
└─$ python3 python-request-multil.py
Cpu_count: 12
Process 1 handle: 833 url (start from 1 to 833
Process 2 handle: 833 url (start from 834 to 1666
Process 3 handle: 833 url (start from 1667 to 2499
Process 4 handle: 833 url (start from 2500 to 3332
Process 5 handle: 833 url (start from 3333 to 4165
Process 6 handle: 833 url (start from 4166 to 4998
Process 7 handle: 833 url (start from 4999 to 5831
Process 8 handle: 833 url (start from 5832 to 6664
Process 9 handle: 833 url (start from 6665 to 7497
Process 10 handle: 833 url (start from 7498 to 8330
Process 11 handle: 833 url (start from 8331 to 9163
Process 12 handle: 836 url (start from 9164 to 9999

[+] Live domain: 4568/9999
--- 184.37868976593018 seconds ---
```

The correct result should be: 9999/9999

---

My previous code does this well, but it only uses threads, so it's too slow in reality:

```py
import time

import requests
import concurrent.futures


def load_url_http(protocol: str, domain: str, timeout: int = 10):
        try:
            conn = requests.head(protocol + "://" + domain, timeout=timeout)
            return conn.status_code
        except Exception:
            return None


#--- main ---#
start_time = time.time()

worker = 400
protocol = "http"
timeout = 10

print("Number of worker:", worker)

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=worker) as executor:
    # The file object that the subdomain lives on will be written to
    file_live_subdomain = open("live_subdomains.txt", "a")
    
    # load domain/subdomain list from file
    URLS = open("subdomains.txt", "r").read().split("\n")
    URLS_length = len(URLS)
    
    # Count the number of live subdomains
    live_count = 0
    
    # Start the load operations and mark each future with its URL
    future_to_url = {
        executor.submit(load_url_http, protocol, url, timeout): url for url in URLS
    }
    
    for i, future in zip(range(URLS_length), concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url)):
        url = future_to_url[future]
        print(f"\r-->  Checking live subdomain.........{i+1}/{URLS_length}", end="")
        try:
            data = future.result()
            
            # If `load_url_http` returns any status code
            if data != None:
                # print(f'{protocol}://{url}:{data}')
                live_count = live_count + 1
                file_live_subdomain.write(f"\n{protocol}://" + url)
        except Exception as exc:
            print(exc)
    print(f"\n[+] Live domain: {live_count}/{URLS_length}", end="")
    file_live_subdomain.close()

print("\n--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

---

Resource:

**subdomains.txt**

```
127.0.0.1:8000?a=1
127.0.0.1:8000?a=1
127.0.0.1:8000?a=1
127.0.0.1:8000?a=1
...
127.0.0.1:8000?a=9999
```

**Simple Server test**

```
python3 -m http.server 8000
```

Comment: hi I am the one who helped you yesterday, What is the problem? I didn't understand

Comment: also the first code you provided **python-request-multil.py** is the code I answered you with yesterday, it doesn't match the output you wrote. please provide the code after the changes you made

Comment: Oh, I can recognize you now when you comment. Regarding yesterday's question, it works as I originally wanted it to. But I realized that live_subdomains.txt is not really recording all the active domains/subdomains. I realize this is a sync problem when writing files, but haven't found a way to solve it yet.

Comment: with 10000 same domain names (E.g: google.com * 10000 times) . then normally if that domain still exists, there will be 10000 domains written to live_subdomains.txt

Comment: when I run the script I posted yesterday on `urls = ["youtube.com"] * 100` I get `http://youtube.com` 100 times in the `live_subdomains.txt` file and the script prints `[+] Live domain: 100/100`

Comment: so I don't understand what isn't working for you

Comment: yes. but if i try with `urls = ["youtube.com"] *1000` the result will be `740/1000`, `767/1000`,... (they are different with each run). and when running with `urls = ["youtube.com"] * 10000` the result will be `about 8000/10000`

Comment: It is possible that after x amount of requests they block your requests, did you try sending this amount of requests to different ulrs?

Comment: Many sites block requests after a certain amount of requests in a given time, because if they won't do this it can be a weakness that someone that wants to make the site crash can exploit

Comment: I thought the same as you and wrote a simple web app using `Flask` and wrote `urls = ["127.0.0.1:5500"] * 1000` to it. The result is similar. I found that with a domain count greater than 1000, it will work fine with a thread count of 10, but I want a thread count greater than 30